# Creating a timetable with SQL (calculated start times for slots) and filtering by a person to show them their slots

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working in iMIS CMS (iMIS 200) and trying to create an IQA (an iMIS query, using SQL) that will give me a timetable of slots assigned to people per day (I've got this working); but then I want to be able to filter that timetable on a person's profile so they just see the slots they are assigned to.

(This is for auditions for an orchestra. So people make an application per instrument, then those applications are assigned to audition slots, of which there are several slots per day)

As the start/end times for slots are calculated using SUM OVER, when I filter this query by the person ID, I lose the correct start/end times for slots (as the other slots aren't in the data for it to SUM, I guess!)

Table structure:

```
tblContacts
===========
ContactID   ContactName
---------------------------
1           Steve Jones
2           Clare Philips
3           Bob Smith
4           Helen Winters
5           Graham North
6           Sarah Stuart
```

```
tblApplications
=============== 
AppID   FKContactID     Instrument
-----------------------------------
1       1               Violin
2       1               Viola
3       2               Cello
4       3               Cello
5       4               Trumpet
6       5               Clarinet
7       5               Horn
8       6               Trumpet
```

```
tblAuditionDays
=============== 
AudDayID  AudDayDate   AudDayVenue    AudDayStart
-------------------------------------------------
1         16-Sep-19    London         10:00
2         17-Sep-19    Manchester     10:00
3         18-Sep-19    Birmingham     13:30
4         19-Sep-19    Leeds          10:00
5         19-Sep-19    Glasgow        11:30
```

```
tblAuditionSlots
================
SlotID  FKAudDayID   SlotOrder  SlotType   SlotDuration   FKAppID
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1       1            1          Audition   20             3
2       1            2          Audition   20             4
3       1            3          Chat       10             3
4       1            5          Chat       10             4
5       1            4          Audition   20             
6       2            1          Audition   20             1
7       2            2          Audition   20             6
8       2            4          Chat       10             6
9       2            3          Chat       10             1
10      2            5          Audition   20             
11      3            2          Chat       10             8
12      3            1          Audition   20             2
13      3            4          Chat       5              2
14      3            3          Audition   20             8
15      5            1          Audition   30             5
16      5            2          Audition   30             7
17      5            3          Chat       15             7
18      5            4          Chat       15             5
```

Current SQL for listing all the slots each day (in date/slot order, with the slot timings calculcated correctly) is:

```
SELECT
    [tblAuditionSlots].[SlotOrder] as [Order],
    CASE
        WHEN
            SUM([tblAuditionSlots].[SlotDuration]) OVER (PARTITION BY [tblAuditionDays].[FKAudDayID] ORDER BY [tblAuditionSlots].[SlotOrder] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) is null 
        THEN
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), [tblAuditionDays].[AudDayStart], 108)
        ELSE
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Dateadd(minute, SUM([tblAuditionSlots].[SlotDuration]) OVER (PARTITION BY [tblAuditionDays].[FKAudDayID] ORDER BY [tblAuditionSlots].[SlotOrder] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), [tblAuditionDays].[AudDayStart]), 108)
        END
    + ' - ' + 
    CASE 
        WHEN
            SUM([tblAuditionSlots].[SlotDuration]) OVER (PARTITION BY [tblAuditionDays].[FKAudDayID] ORDER BY [tblAuditionSlots].[SlotOrder] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) is null
        THEN
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), [tblAuditionDays].[AudDayStart], 108)
        ELSE
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Dateadd(minute, SUM([tblAuditionSlots].[SlotDuration]) OVER (PARTITION BY [tblAuditionDays].[FKAudDayID] ORDER BY [tblAuditionSlots].[SlotOrder] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), [tblAuditionDays].[AudDayStart]), 108)
        END AS [Slot],
    [tblAuditionSlots].[SlotType] AS [Type],
    [tblContacts].[ContactName] as [Name],
FROM
    tblAuditionSlots
    LEFT JOIN tblAuditionDays ON tblAuditionSlots.FKAudDayID = tblAuditionDays.AudDayID
    LEFT JOIN tblApplications ON tblAuditionSlots.FKAppID = tblApplications.AppID
    LEFT JOIN tblContacts ON tblApplications.FKContactID = tblContacts.ContactID
GROUP BY
    [tblAuditionSlots].[SlotOrder],
    [tblAuditionSlots].[SlotType],
    [tblAuditionSlots].[SlotDuration],
    [tblAuditionDays].[AudDayStart],
    [tblContacts].[ContactName],
    [tblContacts].[ContactID],
    [tblAuditionDays].[AudDayID],
    [tblAuditionDays].[AudDayDate]
ORDER BY
    [tblAuditionDays].[DayDate],
    [tblAuditionSlots].[Order]
```

iMIS, the CMS we're using, is limited by what you can create in an IQA (query).
You can basically insert (some) SQL as a column and give it an alias; you can add (non-calculated) fields to the order by; you can't really control the Group By (whatever fields are added are included in the Group By).

Ultimately, I'd like to be able to filter this by a Contact ID so I can see all their audition slots, but with the times correctly calculated.

From the sample data, for example:

```
STEVE JONES AUDITIONS
=====================
Date        Slot             Venue       Type         Instrument
----------------------------------------------------------------
17-Sep-19   10:00 - 10:20    Manchester  Audition     Violin
17-Sep-19   10:40 - 10:50    Manchester  Chat         Violin
18-Sep-19   13:30 - 13:50    Birmingham  Audition     Viola
18-Sep-19   14:30 - 14:35    Birmingham  Chat         Viola

HELEN WINTERS AUDITIONS
=======================
Date        Slot             Venue       Type         Instrument
----------------------------------------------------------------
19-Sep-19   11:30 - 12:00    Glasgow     Audition     Trumpet
19-Sep-19   12:45 - 13:00    Glasgow     Chat         Trumpet
```

Hopefully that all makes sense and I've provided enough information.

(In this version of iMIS [200], you can't do subqueries, in case that comes up...)

Thanks so much in advance for whatever help/tips/advice you can offer!

Chris

Comment: have you tried to partition by personId as well as other partitions?

Comment: I haven't yet, but I think it will still give me the same problem - as I need the calculation over the whole day, not just per person...

Comment: Yes partition both comma separated